# Data in angular is getting displayed and disappearing when used $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-controller, viewdiddisappear

My ejs file is :
     
    
    
    Express App

```
</head>
<body data-ng-app="indexHomepage" data-ng-controller="indexController">
<div style="margin:100px;">
<h1>Express!</h1>


    <table data-ng-repeat="user in users">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4 align="center"><br/><br/>{{user}}<br/></h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>


</div>

<script src="controller/indexHomepageController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my angular controller code is :

```
  var indexHomepage = angular.module('indexHomepage', []);

  indexHomepage.controller('indexController', ['$scope', '$http',     function ($scope, $http) {


  $scope.getUsers = function () {
      $http.get('/getUsers').success(function (response) {

          if (response.responseErrorCode == 503) {
              console.log("No users in database");
          }
          else {

              $scope.users = response;
          }

      });
  }

  }]);
```

when I put console.log in else part of controller instead of setting $scope.users, even then it's showing up and immediately getting disappeared. But if I remove the function and just keep :

```
      $http.get('/getUsers').success(function (response) {

          if (response.responseErrorCode == 503) {
              console.log("No users in database");
          }
          else {

              $scope.users = response;
          }

      });
```

here , it works.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Are you calling `getUsers()` somewhere when you do it the first way?

Comment: No I am not calling getUsers() anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

Do you having plunker Demo ? may be you use **console.log** outside the **else block** , and don't forget that you use **$http** service that the $ajax call is a promise .

$http.get('/getUsers').then(function (response) {

```
      if (response.responseErrorCode == 503) {
          console.log("No users in database");
      }
      else {

          $scope.users = response;
```

console.log('reponse is ' + JSON.stringfy(response));
          }

```
  }).catch(function(err){
```

console.log('err' + err) ;
})

Comment: No I am using webstorm. And With just $http it works but the moment I put it in $scope function, it stops working. I mean the data just shows up and disappears immediately